# Redshift SQL Query - Two data sources with different character: eg François vs Francois

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, diacritics

I am writing a Redshift SQL Query to pull data from two different tables with similar information. One table includes person names with accents, umlauts, n-yays while the other does not. For example one table has François and the other table for the same person has Francois.

Looking for a sql query function that would show all results without accents and other similar encoding (not sure if encoding is the right terminology here).

I know how to find and replace a specific value but that's not what I'm looking for here. Looking to systematically remove all accents, umlauts, n-yays, etc. I found that collate can be used in SQL Server but looks like collate only deals with case sensitivity in Redshift.

Comment: trying this for the time being: translate(u.full_name  ,
    'áàâãäåāăąèééêëēĕėęěìíîïìĩīĭḩóôõöōŏőùúûüũūŭůäàáâãåæçćĉčöòóôõøüùúûßéèêëýñîìíïş',
    'aaaaaaaaaeeeeeeeeeeiiiiiiiihooooooouuuuuuuuaaaaaaeccccoooooouuuuseeeeyniiiis')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unaware of any special function for this, but `translate` can be used. See [Translate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TRANSLATE.html)

```
SELECT
    source_table.person_name
  , translated_table.name_without_accents
FROM source_table
JOIN (
    SELECT
        person_id
      , TRANSLATE(person_name,
                'áàäâãåéèëêíìïîóòöôõúùüûçÁÀÄÂÃÅÉÈËÊÍÌÏÎÓÒÖÔÕÚÙÜÛÇ',
                'aaaaaaeeeeiiiioooouuuucAAAAAAEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUC') AS name_without_accents
    FROM source_table

          /* regex to locate the names containing accented chars */
    WHERE person_name ~ '[áàäâãåéèëêíìïîóòöôõúùüûçÁÀÄÂÃÅÉÈËÊÍÌÏÎÓÒÖÔÕÚÙÜÛÇ]'

    ) AS translated_table ON source_table.person_id = translated_table.person_id;
```

Or, create a view along these lines

```
CREATE VIEW all_names AS
SELECT
    person_id
  , prson_name
  , TRANSLATE(person_name,
            'áàäâãåéèëêíìïîóòöôõúùüûçÁÀÄÂÃÅÉÈËÊÍÌÏÎÓÒÖÔÕÚÙÜÛÇ',
            'aaaaaaeeeeiiiioooouuuucAAAAAAEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUC') AS name_without_accents
FROM source_table
```